# How to loop json in the next ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

How to do a loop to all the number channels in the json?

There are a lot of numbers and I want to alert them one after one:

```
alert(res.available_channels[1].num);
```

until..

```
alert(res.available_channels[***].num);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gnpj5csk/60/

```
var yql_url = 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql';
var url = 'http://***:8080/***.php?username=***&password=***';

$.ajax({
    'url': yql_url,
    //remove this line later
    'data': {
        'q': 'SELECT * FROM json WHERE url="'+url+'"',
        'format': 'json',
        'jsonCompat': 'new',
    },
    'dataType': 'json',
    'success': function(response){

        var res = response.query.results.json;

        //alert only 1 line - works
        //alert(res.available_channels[3].num);

        //alert line by line - not works
        for(var i =0;i< res.available_channels.length;i++){
            alert(res.available_channels[i].num);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with a solution http://jsfiddle.net/gnpj5csk/67/

```js
var yql_url = 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql';
var url = 'http://linux-app.tv:8080/panel_api.php?username=azmir&password=azmir';

$.ajax({
  url: yql_url,
  data: {
    'q': 'SELECT * FROM json WHERE url="'+url+'"',
    'format': 'json',
    'jsonCompat': 'new',
  },
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(response) {
    var res = response.query.results.json;
    var keys = Object.keys(res.available_channels);
    for(var i =0;i< keys.length;i++){
     console.log(res.available_channels[keys[i]].num);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Since `available_channels` is not an array, it's a JSON (key: value). So, you can't loop through as is.

Comment: Thank you very much! i will check it and let you know if i have more question

Comment: @padusi Welcome :) Sure just let me know, will definitely help you.